# OpenSSL Error: Error loading extension section server

Tags: certificate, linux, openssl

The system is Fedora fc21. The objective is to run the examples shown here: [“APACHE web server and SSL authentication”](http://linuxconfig.org/apache-web-server-ssl-authentication)

The `openssl.cnf` file has been created and the following command run:

```
openssl x509 -req -in server.req -CA ca.cer -CAkey ca.key  -set_serial 100 -extfile openssl.cnf -extensions server -days 365 -outform PEM -out server.cer
```

The result is:

```
Error Loading extension section server
140131294459760:error:22097069:X509 V3 routines:DO_EXT_NCONF:invalid extension string:v3_conf.c:139:name=crlDistributionPoints,section=@crl
140131294459760:error:22098080:X509 V3 routines:X509V3_EXT_nconf:error in extension:v3_conf.c:93:name=crlDistributionPoints, value=@crl
```

Similar errors occur with the examples with `-extension client` and `-extension certauth` commands.

What is the cause of this error, how can it be remediated?

Comment: the error says there is a problem in the crlDistributionPoints portion of the config file

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a known [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/easy-rsa/+bug/1346776). There is a resolution posted, copied here for simplicity. In the file "pkitool" replace all occurrences of:

KEY_ALTNAMES="$KEY_CN"

with:

KEY_ALTNAMES="DNS:${KEY_CN}"

This solution worked for me.